# Sorting number in richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, numbers, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox with a lot of number And any number is in a special line and I want Sort The Numbers...
example:
<
99
1
12
1023
>
want to sort
<
1
12
99
1023
>

Comment: What is your problem? getting numbers from rtf or sorting? And what does `special line` mean?

Comment: How many is "lot" of number? What is a "special" line?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: You have to convert the text values to integers so they sort in the order you want, instead of by text value (in other words, the integer order is `1, 12, 99, 1023`, but the text order is `1, 1023, 12, 99`, so you have to: take the text out, convert each value to integer, sort the integers, and then convert to text when you put them back in the `RichTextBox`).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `.Text` property of a RichTextBox to the output from a String.Join if you just want every element to appear on its own line:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 99, 1, 12, 1023 };
Array.Sort(numbers);
richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers);
```

It's difficult to tell what the problem is from your question. If you want to output sorted numbers together on a line with spaces between them, you can join on a space instead:

```
richTextBox1.Text = String.Format("< {0} >", String.Join(" ", numbers));
```

If you're trying to read in numbers in that sort of format, reorder them, and output in the same format, you'll have to parse the string for the individual numbers:

```
string inputRaw = "< 99 1 12 1023 >";
inputRaw = inputRaw.Trim(new[] { '<', '>' });
List<int> inputNumbers = new List<int>();
string[] temporary = inputRaw.Split(' ');
foreach (string s in temporary)
{
    int n;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out n))
        inputNumbers.Add(n);
}
inputNumbers.Sort();

richTextBox1.Text = String.Format("< {0} >", String.Join(" ", inputNumbers));
```

Comment: +1 - Looks like you and I interpreted this differently. Sounds like he needs to pull the numbers **from** the textbox, rather than output them to it. Nice of you to help out regardless instead of just downvoting and sitting quiet!

Comment: You are a kind soul for bothering to answer this.

Comment: I just hope part or all of it is useful, and that by being kind, the OP will hang around and improve as well. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers into an array and then call the Array.Sort method.

Comment: or put the numbers into a List<T> and call it's Sort() Method as well.

Comment: or use any container that implements IEnumerable<T> and call [OrederBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966).

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is just an output where you place those numbers, it'd be more smart to sort the values before placing them in the textbox using `Array.sort`.

If the textbox is actually an input where the user provides the values, you'll first want to take each line content and convert into a number, storing in an array as you go:

```
int[] linesAsNumbers = new int[richTextBox1.Lines.Length]; // We'll store the numbers in this array

int i = 0; // Keep an index of where to place the incoming numbers
foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    linesAsNumbers[i++] = Convert.ToInt32(line); // Convert each line into a number and store it into our newly created array
}
```

Now you'll have to sort the array using Array.Sort and join all the numbers back into a string:

```
Array.Sort(linesAsNumbers); // It automatically sorts from lowest to highest

richTextBox1.Text = String.Join<int>("\n", linesAsNumbers);
```

This of course chokes if any of the lines contains non-number characters, but works with your scenary.